# Javascript/ReactJS execution of .then() is being performed too early

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch

I want to rerender my React Component, once a POST-fetch has successfully performed. However when I console.log the execution times I notice that the order of execution is off.
I am using the following code to get the time:

```
function getTime(input) {
  var date = input ? new Date(input) : new Date();
  return {
      hours : date.getHours(),
      minutes : date.getMinutes(),
      seconds : date.getSeconds(),
      milliseconds : date.getMilliseconds()
  }
}
```

In the main component I want to rerender after the fetch I am calling the following function, that is being imported from a seperate rest.js file:

```
fetchPushNewCourse(finalEvents).then(console.log("then 2 performed at", this.getTime()));
```

The function itself looks like that:

```
export async function fetchPushNewCourse(args){
  await fetch(`/calendar/post`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ message: args }),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => {
    console.log("then 1 performed at", getTime())
    return res.json();
  })
}
```

I want "then 2" only be console.logged after the fetch has been performed, however it always gets executed about one second earlier. I seem to have a basic misunderstanding how promises work.

Comment: .then accepts a **function** as an argument - check what you're passing instead - hint: `undefined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing lambda with `console.log('then 2')`, instead of it you are invoking it in the place of declaration.

It could be easily fixed:

```js
fetchPushNewCourse(finalEvents).then(() => console.log("then 2 performed at", this.getTime()));
```